# Using a file as a storage medium for a large Map in java

Tags: java, file, dictionary, data-structures, collections

I have a large amount of data I need to store in a `Map<String, int...>`. I need to be able to perform the following functions:

1. `containsKey(String key)`
2. `get(String key).add(int value)`
3. `put(String key, singletonList(int value))`
4. `entrySet().iterator()`

I originally was just using a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>` where `singletonList` is a function that creates a new `ArrayList<Integer>` and adds the given `value` to it. However, this strategy does not scale well to the amount of data I am using as it stores everything in the RAM and my RAM is not big enough to store all the data.

My next idea was to just dump everything into a file. However, this would mean that `get`, `containsKey`, and `put` would become very expensive operations, which is not at all desirable. Of course, I could keep everything sorted, but that is often difficult in a large file.

I was wondering if there is a better strategy out there.

Comment: is swapping/virtual memory not an option here?

Comment: @Natecat I'd prefer an in-program solution. I'm working with a PC not a dedicated server here and I don't want to mess with it unnecessarily.

Comment: Have you looked into [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/)? _MapDB is embedded database engine. It provides java collections backed by disk or memory database store. MapDB has excellent performance comparable to java.util.HashMap and other collections, but is not limited by GC_.

Comment: @Voicu that looks like it would work. Write it up as an answer and I'll accept or if you got it from another SO problem, feel free to mark this post as a duplicate and I'll second. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an embedded database engine (key-value store), such as [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/), is one way to go.

From MapDB's official website:

> MapDB is embedded database engine. It provides java collections backed by disk or memory database store. MapDB has excellent performance comparable to java.util.HashMap and other collections, but is not limited by GC. It is also very flexible engine with many storage backend, cache algorithms, and so on. And finally MapDB is pure-java single 400K JAR and only depends on JRE 6+ or Android 2.1+.

If that works for you, you can start from [here](http://www.mapdb.org/doc/getting-started.html).

Comment: this appears to be working well. Thanks. I would like to add that this works not only with `Map` but with `Set`.

Answer (score -1):

Why don`t you try ObjectOutputStream to store the map to a file and you can use ObjectInputStream to get data from the map.
I hope it would help you.

Comment: The reason I want a file is to not have to store the entire map in RAM. this wouldn't fix that problem